# How to POST a new formData in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data

Before submitting the form I did some modifications in existing formData.After that, I just post the new formData.But Didn't work.

The old form was submitted.Still, existing formData is available in the request body

Could anyone have an idea?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var loaded = false;

window.onload = function() {
  loaded = true;
} 
document.querySelector("#mainForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  prepareOCPDepEntries();
  if(!loaded){
    alert(errorText(2314));
    e.preventDefault();  //Stop form submission before the page is loaded
  }
}); 

function prepareOCPDepEntries(){

    var formEl = document.forms.mainForm;
    const formData = new FormData(formEl);
    var res = "";

     for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log("PAIR>>",pair);
       if(pair[0].startsWith("_")){
        res = res +"|"+ pair;
        formData.delete(pair[0]);
       }
      /*if(isButton && pair[0] === 'buttonClicked' && pair[1] != ""){
          document.getElementById("buttonClick").value = pair[1];
      }*/
    }
    document.getElementById("depEntry").value = res;

    
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.open("POST", "/Group/Calling_Plan/Outgoing/index.jsp");
     request.send(formData);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault();` outside of `if` as it seems that you are already `post` data from `prepareOCPDepEntries` so it doesn't need to `submit` `form` as `default` action.